# Conditional calculation in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet for keeping track of printer toner replacement with the following columns:

```
Printer Name
Date replaced
Page count
Toner Page count
```

I keep a running log each time a specific printer has a toner replaced and pull a page count each time.  I need a way to calculate the amount of pages printed per toner. So I need to match the printer name, find the last date the toner was replaced and use the page count to calculate how many pages were printed on that toner.

Comment: So your table looks like | Printer Name | Date Replaced | Page Count | Toner Page Count |. What data do you enter manually, what data will be available, what data is missing/are you trying to calculate?

Comment: -1: Sorry, you have not shown any your own effort. Stackoverflow is not a place for solving your homework instead of you. Try doing something yourself first. Then paste here your solution, tell what it does, what you want it to do. Be very specific in your question. The to remove all the irrelevant stuff so you ask one single and clear thing.

Comment: @HonzaZidek, give him a chance to edit the question. simoco, please put more information about your spreadsheet, setup, data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable and a formula like this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(F2),ISBLANK(F3)),"",F3-F2)
```

copied down might suit:

[image: SO22995443 example]